# Issues with Binding Model to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

When attempting to bind a model to a view, I'm getting a 404 error. The ActionResult is called 'SortDesc' but the view is just a standard 'Index' view. I understand that this isn't loading because the there is now view called 'SortDesc'. However I have two buttons one to sort data ascending and one to sort data decending hence the two seperate functions. I'm just not sure what the best solution would be here, either to continue with the two seperate functions and somehow pass in the correct view to load or to create a new, single HttpPost function on Index that will know which button has been clicked and sort accordingly. Here's the code I have so far:

Models:

```
public class NumberSetList
{
    public int NumberSetListId { get; set; }
    public List<NumberList> Numbers { get; set; }

    public string SortOrder { get; set; }
}

public class NumberList
{
    public int NumberListId { get; set; } 
    public int Number1 { get; set; }
    public int Number2 { get; set; }
    public int Number3 { get; set; }
    public int Number4 { get; set; }
    public int Number5 { get; set; }
    public string SortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Razor:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "csi media web test";
}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>csi media web test</h1>
    <p class="lead">Liane Stevenson</p>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i> Enter Your Four Numbers</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form class="form-inline">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="number1">1st Number</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="number1" name="Number1" placeholder="#1">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="number2">2nd Number</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="number2" name="Number2" placeholder="#2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="number3">3rd Number</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="number3" name="Number3" placeholder="#3">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="number4">4th Number</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="number4" name="Number4" placeholder="#4">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 text-right">
                        <a class="btn btn-default" href="@Url.Action("SortDesc", "Home")"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></i> Sort Desc</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-default" href="@Url.Action("SortAsc", "Home")"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></i> Sort Asc</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <p>
                    @if (Model != null)
                    {
                        foreach (int number in Model.Numbers)
                        {
                            <span class="label label-info">@number</span>
                        }
                    }   
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Home Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SortDesc([Bind(Include = "Number1, Number2, Number3, Number4")] NumberSetList model)
{

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        NumberSetList list = new NumberSetList();
        List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
        numbers.Add(model.Number1);
        numbers.Add(model.Number2);
        numbers.Add(model.Number3);
        numbers.Add(model.Number4);
        numbers.OrderByDescending(i => i);
        list.SortOrder = "Desc";
        return View(list);
    }

}
```

Comment: In the action, the variable `numbers` is not assigned to anything. How is the view going to be made aware of it? You need to set `list.numbers = numbers;`

Comment: That throws an error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<CSIMediaASPTest.Models.NumberList>' CSIMediaASPTest

Comment: My bad. yeah scratch that. missed the `List<int>`

Comment: What are you actually trying to do in that action?

Comment: So I changed the list in the NumberSetModel to List<int> - dont really need the extra class now I look at it -  so now numbers is null because it's not picking up the values of the inputs - I want to grab the inputs, sort them, add them to the model and then display the model with the correct order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
public class NumberSetList {
    public int NumberSetListId { get; set; }
    public List<NumberSetItem> Numbers { get; set; }
    public string SortOrder { get; set; }
}

public class NumberSetItem {
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

, use `for` loop to create inputs for the numbers

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="form-group">
            @if (Model != null && Model.Numbers != null) {
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Numbers.Count; i++) {
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Numbers[i].Value, "Number " + (i+1).ToString())
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Numbers[i].Value, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                }
               <div class="col-md-3 text-right">
                   <input id="SortOrder" value="Desc" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></i> Sort Desc</input>
                   <input id="SortOrder" value="Asc" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></i> Sort Asc</input>
               </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

And in the View

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(NumberSetList model) {
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
        return View();
    } else {
        var numbers = model.SortOrder == "Desc" ?
            model.Numbers.OrderByDescending(n => n.Value) : 
            model.Numbers.OrderBy(n => n.Value);
        model.Numbers = numbers.ToList();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: Generates an error: An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation - thats on 'm.Numbers[i]'

Comment: Very close now - doesn't pass in the model - I've set values for the model in ActionResult Index() but they aren't carried through to SortDesc

Comment: That is because the links are doing a GET not a POST which they cannot. Update the Form to point to an action `@using (Html.BeginForm())` and include the sort as a property for the model instead of two separate actions.

Comment: Whats the best way to pass the sort order over? Is there a way to pick up the text on the link or something?

Comment: @WebDevelopWolf check last update. note action name changed as well.

Comment: Clicking the buttons doesn't do anything at all now it's completely stopped firing - tried chaning to a submit button but that just rests the text boxes

Comment: Recheck the razor code and make sure you followed it like in the latest update.

Comment: Sorted - I have two form tags - thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the issue using a variety of techniques.

Pass the name of the view into the `View` method like this:

```
return View("Index", list);
```

The `View` method has many overloads and you can see them all [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view(v=vs.118).aspx). It is nice to get yourself familiar with the overloads for scenarios like the one you are facing.

If your view is not in the same folder as the action, you will need to pass the path for the view instead of just the name.

Another way is to have a single action and you can call this one Index as well but this one will take a model as an argument. Your model can have the numbers and an enum for sort: Desc, Asc. In your action method you can analyze the model, and do whatever is needed.

The approach with the model is the one I prefer.

**EDIT**

I just noticed you have this line of code in your view:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="@Url.Action("SortDesc", "Home")"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></i> Sort Desc</a>
```

That will trigger an HTTP GET and therefore it will not hit your `SortDsc` action method. Remove POST from your action method or use a post technique (Form) to hit your action method using POST.

**EDIT 2**

Honestly what you are doing is far simpler than you are making it. First thing is when you are using `Url.Actio` you are not passing nothing to your action method so how will it know about the numbers? I would normally call my action method using AJAX and get the result and display the result.

Without AJAX, you need to use one form for ascending and one for descending. Or you can use a radio button so user can select the order first.

Here is some code to do it using radio buttons.

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SortDesc([Bind( Include = "Number1, Number2, Number3, Number4, SortOrder" )] NumberList model) {

   if( !ModelState.IsValid ) {
      return View("Index");
   }
   model.Numbers = new List<int>();
   model.Numbers.Add( model.Number1 );
   model.Numbers.Add( model.Number2 );
   model.Numbers.Add( model.Number3 );
   model.Numbers.Add( model.Number4 );
   model.Numbers.Add( model.Number5 );
   if (model.SortOrder == "Desc" ) {
      model.Numbers = model.Numbers.OrderByDescending( i => i ).ToList();
   }
   else {
      model.Numbers = model.Numbers.OrderBy( i => i ).ToList();
   }

   return View("Index", model);

}
```

Model:

```
public class NumberList {
   public int Number1 { get; set; }
   public int Number2 { get; set; }
   public int Number3 { get; set; }
   public int Number4 { get; set; }
   public int Number5 { get; set; }
   public int NumberListId { get; set; }
   public List<int> Numbers { get; set; }
   public string SortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@using( Html.BeginForm( "SortDesc", "Home", FormMethod.Post ) ) {
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i> Enter Your Four Numbers</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form class="form-inline">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="number1">1st Number</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="number1" name="Number1" placeholder="#1">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="number2">2nd Number</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="number2" name="Number2" placeholder="#2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="number3">3rd Number</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="number3" name="Number3" placeholder="#3">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="number4">4th Number</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="number4" name="Number4" placeholder="#4">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="radio" class="form-control" id="number4" name="SortOrder" value="Desc">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="radio" class="form-control" id="number4" name="SortOrder" value="Asc">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3 text-right">
                        <button class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></i> Sort </button>
                        @*<a class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></i> Sort Asc</a>*@
                    </div>
                </form>
                <p>
                    @if( Model != null ) {
                        foreach( int number in Model.Numbers ) {
                        <span class="label label-info">@number</span>
                        }
                    }
                </p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

}
```

Comment: Same problem -  The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Home/SortDesc

Comment: You need to pass the numbers into your action. Do you need help with that as well?

Comment: The action method `SortDesc` has attribute `[HttpPost]`, so make sure you didn't call it using `GET`. In other words, just opening /Home/SortDesc in your browser is not possible, it would **have** to be a `POST` call coming from some other page (e.g. /Home/Index).

Comment: I thought that was what [Bind(Include = "Number1, Number2, Number3, Number4")] did?

Comment: That fires the action which is great but still doesn't pass in the numbers from the four inputs?

Comment: I've added the models so you might be be able to seewhat I'm trying to do more clearly

Comment: Ok I see what you are trying to do. See my edit 2. But please, use AJAX for scenarios like this. But that will get you what you want. Copy everything I have and try it.

Comment: Never mind. I see Nkosi already answered you. Use his solution instead. It is better.